# Character encoding is missing at a point

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, encoding, utf-8

I'm trying to insert data in a mysql database. These data often has german umlaute in it.

I'm using this method:

```
function insertMenue($content, $date) {
    $session = $_SESSION['aid'];
    global $pdo;
    $pdo->exec('SET CHARACTER SET utf8');
    $params = ["menue", "<p>".changeAttr($content)."</p>", $date, $session];
    // Check all your params are set...
    // Although you may want to consider checking these before entering this block
    print_r($params);
    echo "c".changeAttr($content);
    print_r("v".  changeAttr($content));

    $sql = "INSERT INTO menue( type
                             , content
                             , date
                             , creator
                             )
            VALUES( ?
                  , ?
                  , ?
                  , ?
                  )";
    try {
        $sth = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $sth->execute($params);
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        throw new pdoDbException($e);
    }
}
```

As you see I'm already doing some debugging.
I'm getting the data from an Excel .xls file.
The print_r grants an output like this:

```
Salat
****
Trutenpiccata Tomatensauce
Spaghetti
Gem�sebuffet
-
****
Saisonfr�chte
```

When I check the mysql database everything including the � and after gets deleted.
Like:

```
 Salat
 ****
 Trutenpiccata Tomatensauce
 Spaghetti
 Gem
```

I tried to encode the data as utf-8 from the insert method on and I set the database to utf-8 by:

```
ALTER DATABASE mensaapp CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
ALTER TABLE menue CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

Where do I miss the point to encode the data to utf-8?

Comment: Are you sure `$params` are in utf8?

Comment: Also, verify your client handshake settings....

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through  you need to make sure EVERY stage of your system is using the same charset, or hooked together with appropriate translation logic.

Comment: @venca, how can I ensure this?

Comment: `utf8_encode($content)` did the job very well.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the charset in your html code too.
This is what helped me with my umlaute ;)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" /><!-- THIS IS WHAT NEEDED -->
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

After adding it, i got not problems.
I too use UTF-8 in the complete database, so this should not be the problem.